# No sound after fresh installation

Tags: sound

Fresh installation of version 14.04 64-bit on a Sony VAIO. Completelety reformatted HD. Single OS system. No sound of any kind. But there is sound from plugged in headphones. Everything is unmuted in Sound Settings. I don't see any Hardware tab there. In the Output tab there are 2 options: Digital Output S/PDIF (Built-in Audio) and Headphones (Built-in Audio). It looks like Ubuntu doesn't see my sound hardware (most likely it is a sound processor built into the motherboard and not a stand alone sound card).
I ran `pacmd dump-volumes` command and got this:

```
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> Sink 20: reference = 0:  80% 1:  80%, real = 0:  80% 1:  80%, soft = 0: 100% 1: 100%, current_hw = 0:  80% 1:  80%, save = yes
Source 1: reference = 0: 101% 1: 101%, real = 0: 101% 1: 101%, soft = 0: 101% 1: 101%, current_hw = 0: 100% 1: 100%, save = yes
    Output 5: volume = 0: 100%, reference_ratio = 0: 100%, real_ratio = 0: 100%, soft = 0: 100%, volume_factor = 0: 100%, volume_factor_source = 0: 100% 1: 100%, save = no
Source 21: reference = 0: 100% 1: 100%, real = 0: 100% 1: 100%, soft = 0: 100% 1: 100%, current_hw = 0: 100% 1: 100%, save = no
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated, but I would prefer as many details as possible since Ubuntu is totally new to me.

Comment: So is this external speakers that aren't working, or built in laptop ones?

Answer (score 0):

Install sound card drivers and needed packages:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-uname -r` alsa-base alsa-base-udeb alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-oss alsa-source alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils alsa-utils-udeb alsamixergui
```